# Python: create a variable format string for 2D Array

Tags: python, string.format

I am going currently through the book Supercharged Python and there is one problem, that I would like to try to optimize. I want to create a string for .format for a variable size of a 2D array.

```
def print_2dArray_opt(lst: list):
    width = 1
    row_string = '' 

    for r in lst:
        for c in r:
            temp = len(str(c))
            row_string = row_string + '{:{w}}' + ' ' 
            if temp > width:
                width = temp
        row_string = row_string + '\n'

    print(row_string.format(lst, w = width)) # That of course doesn't work


print_2dArray_opt([[1, 10, 100, 200],
                   [1, 10, 100, 200],
                   [1, 10, 100, 200],
                   [1, 10, 10000, 200]
                   ])
```

But I can't figure out how to formulate that print statement so that it can work.
Any suggestions?

The output should look like this:

```
   1     10     100    200  
   1     10     100    200  
   1     10     100    200  
   1     10    10000   200
```

The easy solution with multiple print statements is like this:

```
def print_2dArray(lst: list):
    # simple solution
    width = 1

    for r in lst:
        for c in r:
            temp = len(str(c))
            if temp > width:
                width = temp

    for r in lst:
        for c in r:
            print("{:^{w}}".format(c, w=width + 2), end='')
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this format style

```
f'{c:{width}}'
```

**so updated_code:**

```
def print_2dArray_opt(lst: list):
    width = 1
    row_string = '' 

    for r in lst:
        for c in r:
            temp = len(str(c))             
            if temp > width:
                width = temp

            row_string = row_string + (f'{c:{width}}').strip() + " "
        row_string = row_string + "\n"
        
    # => if you want to make it depend on max width use below code
# ============================================================
    text = ""
    for i in row_string.split("\n"):
        for j in i.split(" "):
            text += j.ljust(width+3)
        text += "\n"
    print(text)
# ============================================================

print_2dArray_opt([[1, 10, 100, 200],
                [1, 10, 100, 200],
                [1, 10, 100, 200],
                [1, 10, 10000, 200]
                ])
```

**or use this row:**

```
row_string = row_string + (f'{c:{width}}').strip().ljust(10) + " "
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. Unfortunately not exactly what I was looking for: With your proposal I get a nice table. But the numbers are not aligned according to the "longest" value. I would like to have the width of each element the according to the longest of the elements.

I updated the question.

Comment: so use ljust(10) it works ? answer updated